# Unwanted black cells at the bottom of a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

[Screenshots showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFGg4.jpg)

I'm using custom style cells as you can see. The problem only seems to occur when there aren't enough cells to fill the screen (i.e. you can see them all without scrolling down). Ideally it would just have a plain white background at the bottom of the UITableView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TableView.backgroundColor ...?`

Comment: I think u r set tableview background colour black and cell bg colour white. please check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your `tableView` has black background. Try setting other color (`[UIColor whiteColor]` for example) or

```
self.menuTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

to make look just empty view (without separators)

Comment: Thank you, I'm an eejit.